# Pandas swap columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, swap

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
0   A     7     NaN
1   B     16    NaN
1   B     16    15
```

What I want to do is to swap Col2 with Col3 where the value of Col3 is `NaN`. Based on other posts and answers on SO, I have this code so far:

```
df[['Col2', 'Col3']] = df[['Col3', 'Col2']].where(df[['Col3']].isnull())
```

But this does not seem to be working properly and gives me the following:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
0   A     NaN   NaN
1   B     NaN   NaN
1   B     NaN   NaN
```

Is there something that I might be missing here?

**Update:** My desired output looks like:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
0   A     NaN   7
1   B     NaN   16
1   B     16    15
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by when Col3 is None? If all elements are NaN or would a single element suffice?

Comment: @ayhan For some rows, the value of Col3 is NaN and when that happens I want to swap it with Col2. I edited the question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `loc` to do the swap:

```
df.loc[df['Col3'].isnull(), ['Col2', 'Col3']] = df.loc[df['Col3'].isnull(), ['Col3', 'Col2']].values
```

Note that `.values` is required to make sure the swap is done properly, otherwise Pandas would try to align based on index and column names, and no swap would occur.

You can also just reassign each row individually, if you feel the code is cleaner:

```
null_idx = df['Col3'].isnull()
df.loc[null_idx, 'Col3'] = df['Col2']
df.loc[null_idx, 'Col2'] = np.nan
```

The resulting output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A   NaN   7.0
1    B   NaN  16.0
2    B  16.0  15.0
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this: (its faster)

```
df["Col3"], df["Col2"] = np.where(df['Col3'].isnull(), [df["Col2"], df["Col3"]], [df["Col3"], df["Col2"] ])
df

     Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A   NaN   7.0
1    B   NaN  16.0
1    B  16.0  15.0


    %timeit df.loc[df['Col3'].isnull(), ['Col2', 'Col3']] = df.loc[df['Col3'].isnull(), ['Col3', 'Col2']].values
100 loops, best of 3: 2.68 ms per loop


    %timeit df["Col3"], df["Col2"] = np.where(df['Col3'].isnull(), [df["Col2"], df["Col3"]], [df["Col3"], df["Col2"] ])
1000 loops, best of 3: 592 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you Merlin. Any idea why this approach is faster than the other one?

Comment: I know, I was wondering what is causing the speed up. And also I did upvote your answer.